# "Join this community" gives 404 when called from add comment on a site meta

Tags: bug, login, per-site-meta

Steps to reproduce:

1. Goto a post on a meta site you don't have account on ([this is lowest user count site if you want to try](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/209))
2. Click "add a comment"
3. Click "join this community"
4. Click "confirm and create this account"
5. Receive 404 page not found

I have seen this on multiple site metas (Chemistry and Portuguese).

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to try to join a meta without joining the main site. I'd suggest that this be resolved by _removing_ the "join this community" functionality for per-site metas.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It redirects to the main site. Which I suspect is what happened here... and then something is jacked up with the return url. I'll look.

Comment: @Adam 5 months later, any updates?

Comment: @Adam two years later, any updates? :)

Answer (score 4):

Successfully reproduced the error.

It would be better if the "Join this Community" link re-directs to the main site rather than showing a 404.

I have successfully created an account with those steps, but on the main site.

So, *joining the meta rather than from the main site* makes no sense. So, the meta's *join this community* link redirecting to that of the main site would make more sense.