# I signed up for Super User and got redirected to a 404 page

Tags: bug, login, confirmation

I aready had a stack overflow account. Now I wanted to sign up for superuser.
I clicked the "join this community" button and needed to confirm:

[image: confirm new account]
Clicking the button redirected me to:
[image]
(https://superuser.com/login?newreg=91f...)

Comment: Hm, that's new. Is the URL you included at the end the one that was in the address bar when you got redirected? Did the same thing happen on any of the other sites you joined so far?

Comment: Weird. I just signed up for a new site ([bricks.SE], FWIW) to test this, and got redirected to the front page (without `/login`) as expected.

Comment: Sure you didn't click it from the "add comment", as reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269699/join-this-community-gives-404-when-called-from-add-comment-on-a-site-meta) before?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: That looks like a different issue (although I suppose they could be related). For one thing, the bug you linked to occurs on meta sites, and results in the account creation failing. The one reported here apparently occurred on a main Q&A site, and (judging by the `newreg=` parameter in the URL) the account creation seems to have succeeded.

Comment: @AdamLear (wups, forgot about this post here, sorry) I tried it on other pages as well But stackexchange was the only one this happened. The link at the end was the link I from the mail to click on (it had some more random characters)